# Average/Min/Max method not working in java eclipse with window builder

Tags: java, swing, methods, actionlistener, windowbuilder

So I've got my csv file reader working to the best I can make it and decided to just leave it as it is.

The next thing is creating the average/min/max method in java. The csv file that I'm reading looks like this;

[image]

Below is the code for the JButton called "Average".

```
JButton btnaverage = new JButton("Average");
btnaverage.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

/****
* finds the value of all elements in an array
* argument - array of double
* @return - double
***/

//averageTxt.setText(array1.findAverageFromArray()+""); this is just an example.

}
});
```

I've been told to put the method outside of the constructor in the java code (basically meaning at the end of the code for the average jbutton. However I'm not too sure what code is used to link my average jbutton to use the average method which is below;

```
public double findAverageFromArray(double[] array){
double average;
double sum=0;
for(int i=0; i<array.length;++i)
{
sum += array[i];
}
average = sum/array.length;
return average;
}
}
```

What the idea is to have the average method find the averages (from the csv file) for temperature, light and vcc.

I am a java newbie so please be nice :(

Comment: Please post the *relevant* (only) parts of the data and code directly in your question (rather than posting links). That way all the info needed to answer your question is in the question.

Comment: @Bohemian sorry about that.

Comment: No need to apologise, it's not a big deal - just edit your question and replace the links with your data/code

Comment: @Bohemian actually I've found some method code for average min max that makes more sense. Going to try that first then edit this post if I need help. (Most likely will).

Comment: @Bohemian I've edited my post. Hope this gives you a more clear insight into my problem.

Comment: Where in your code does the array come from? The one you pass to the method.

Comment: @JosefN Not sure if this is correct myself to be honest but from what I've been taught, the btnaverage.addActionListener (I double clicked the jbutton labelled Average so that I can link my average method (which I have put outside of the constructor at the end of my java code) to my Average jbutton to find the average from my csv file.

Answer (score 1):

> *"However I'm not too sure what code is used to link my average jbutton to use the average method which is below;"*

This is your current code:

```
JButton btnaverage = new JButton("Average");
btnaverage.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    //averageTxt.setText(array1.findAverageFromArray()+""); this is just an example.

    }
});
```

You seem to have this `array1.findAverageFromArray()` wrong. The method takes a double argument. So without seeing any other context, I'd say just to do this

```
averageTxt.setText(String.valueOf(findAverageFromArray(array1));
```

Pass the array to the method. If `array1` contains the relevant data, this should work.

**Test Run**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class AverageTest extends JPanel {

    private static final int DIM_WIDTH = 500;
    private static final int DIM_HEIGHT = 500;

    JButton jbtAverage = new JButton("Get Average");
    JTextField jtfAverage = new JTextField(15);
    double[] array1 = {78.2, 65.5, 98.5, 86.5, 75.5, 69.5, 96.2, 102.5, 75.8};

    public AverageTest() {
        // Set label to chow array
        JLabel arrayLabel = new JLabel(" ");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Temps: ");
        for (double d : array1) {
            sb.append(String.valueOf(d)).append(", ");
        }
        arrayLabel.setText(sb.toString());
        arrayLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

        // Label for average
        JLabel averageLabel = new JLabel("Average");

        // JPanel for average label and average text field
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.add(averageLabel);
        panel1.add(jtfAverage);

        // add components to main panel
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(arrayLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(panel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(jbtAverage, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        jbtAverage.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                jtfAverage.setText(String.valueOf(findAverageFromArray(array1)));
            }
        });
    }

    public double findAverageFromArray(double[] array) {
        double average;
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
            sum += array[i];
        }
        average = sum / array.length;
        return average;
    }

    public static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new AverageTest());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: //averageTxt.setText(array1.findAverageFromArray()+""); that code is just an example made up by my friend. I've tried your code but averageTxt at the beginning gives me an red cross error. Not sure what exactly is going on but the end result should be the Average button in my GUI linked to the average method.

Comment: Did you run my program? You can review it to compare it to yours and see what you possibly did wrong. I used the same line I suggested

Comment: I used you `findAverageFromArray` method. You can see in my `actionPerformed()`. If you want to show your complete program. I can take a look at it for you to see what you have wrong.

Comment: I've ran your program code and I'm just going to go over your code and see what I've done wrong. Bare with em *concentration mode*

Comment: You should learn to hard code yourself before trying to use a GUI tool.  It will become a much better programmer. I personally don't like the autogenerated code. It's make the code look really messy. Take a look at [**`Swing tutorial`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)